# Blazor best practice for Non-nullable warnings

Tags: .net-core, blazor

With blazor I get Non-nullable warnings all around the code. Those warnings seems to be wrong, however solving them introduces a lot of code with the only purpose to hide the warning while the value will never be null.

What is the best practice to solve or hide those warnings?

Example:

```
[Inject] private IStringLocalizer<Element> L { get; set; }
Element.razor.cs(5, 50): [CS8618] Non-nullable property 'L' must contain a non-null value when exiting constructor. Consider declaring the property as nullable.
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As Blazor will always assign the property to a non-null value before executing your code, it is safe to disable the warning using `= default!`.

```cs
[Inject] private IStringLocalizer<Element> L { get; set; } = default!;
```

Comment: This didn't work for me. When I set the non-nullable to default I got a "cannot convert literal to non-nullable value" error.

Answer (score 4):

I had similar problems when I first moved over to `Nullable`.

The `Inject` issue can be resolved like this:

```cs
[Inject] private IStringLocalizer<Element> L { get; set; } = default!;
```

You can use the null forgiving `!` operator where you know the object won't be null, or the null coalescing operator to check for null and return a default value.

```cs
private string? value;
private bool hasValue => value is not null;

string SomeMethod()
{
  return hasValue
    ? value!
    : string.empty;
}

//or 

string SomeOtherMethod()
{
  return value ?? string.empty;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `[NotNull]` annotation from `System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis`. Not sure, when it was added though:

```cs
[Inject]
[NotNull]
protected IStringLocalizer<Element>? Localizer { get; set; }
```

This is how we use it. Problem: This still only works on properties, not on fields.

Comment: With [NotNull] I do still get the CS8618 Non-nullable warning. But you have an ? as it is a nulalble value.

Comment: @Taco I don't get these warnings (And they're not in e.g. `<NoWarn>` in the projects)... Having `?` together with `[NotNull]` is ok as it works for us. Do you use this on properties with `{ get; set; }` or on fields? It won't work with fields...

Comment: With { get; set; }

Comment: Strange... I use this in several projects like this (And even `<TreatWarningsAsErrors>true</TreatWarningsAsErrors>` is set in the project, there is no error)...

Comment: It is the combination`?` with `[NotNull]` that does the trick... It is a bit counterintuitive but works. Thanks.

Comment: @Taco That's the thing, yes. Still strange, I agree.